# excel vba create appointment in someone elses calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have about 10 calendars shared when I open Outlook. I have all the information about the appointment I want to make in Excel, But I don't know how to assign it to one of the calendars that I share. How do I reference someone else's calendar, and put an appointment into it?

Thank you

Comment: browse through your sessions (application.session) and choose the calendar-Folder from the desired session.

Answer (score 0):

H,

The [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Set CalendarFolder = _  
  myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
  (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
  CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

The [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article describe how to create an appointment in the folder.