# Send Appointment VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, appointment

So, I've been wrestling with this task for WAY too long now. I am trying to make a button that creates an appointment and sends it to someone. So far, I've been successful in creating the appointment with the variables I want, but I can't figure out how to send it to the right person. Or send it at all for that matter. I'm very new to Outlook applications within VBA, so be gentle with me, but here is my code so far:

```
Sub appt()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim duedate As String
Dim currentrow As String
Dim currentsheet As String
Dim owner As String    

currentsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
currentrow = Range("C10:C" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
duedate = Range("C" & currentrow).Offset(0, 1)
owner = Range("C" & currentrow).Offset(0, 2)
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .Recipients = Range("M3")
    .Subject = "Next PDB Task for " & currentsheet
    .Importance = True
    .Start = "8:00 AM" & duedate
    .End = "8:00 AM" & Format(Date + 5)
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 10080
    .Body = "Text and Stuff"
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Unload Emy
End Sub
```

So, this is definitely grabbing the information I want from the sheet it's run in, however it's not going anywhere. Do I need to use something other than .Recipients? Is it possible to forward this (with .Forward maybe?)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

P.S. The email address I want to send the appointment to is in cell M3.

Comment: Where's the `Send` command? Also, you say it's not going to the right person in the top paragraph, but then say it's definitely grabbing the info you want.  Is it correctly filling in the email, just not sending?

Comment: outMail.to = range("m3")

Comment: There is no send command. Do I need one? It's not creating a mail item, just an appointment that opens up on my screen. And it's pulling the right information from the sheet to fill out the appt macro, that's what I meant. - To BruceWayne

Comment: To Dy.Lee - Didn't work. Any other suggestions/additions

Comment: awww guys don't give up on me now :-(

Comment: comment out the `on error ...` line and run code again

Comment: put the `stop` command before the `Set OutMail = Nothing` line

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the scripts, but it looks like they will do what you want.

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Set CalendarFolder = _  
  myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
  (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
  CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

[excel vba create appointment in someone elses calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025736/excel-vba-create-appointment-in-someone-elses-calendar)

```
Sub MultiCalendars()
    Dim objPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As Outlook.CalendarModule
    Dim objGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim calItem As Object
    Dim mtgAttendee As Outlook.Recipient

    Dim i As Integer

    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    DoEvents

    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)

    With objModule.NavigationGroups
        Set objGroup = .GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olMyFoldersGroup)

    ' To use a different calendar group
'        Set objGroup = .Item("Shared Calendars")
    End With


    For i = 1 To objGroup.NavigationFolders.Count
        If (objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i).Folder.FullFolderPath = "\\Mailbox - Doe, John T\Calendar") Then
            Set objNavFolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
            Set calItem = objNavFolder.Folder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
            calItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            calItem.Subject = "Test Meeting - Ignore"
            calItem.Location = "TBD Location"
            calItem.Start = #1/19/2015 1:30:00 PM#
            calItem.Duration = 90
            Set mtgAttendee = calItem.Recipients.Add("John Doe")
            mtgAttendee.Type = olRequired
            Set mtgAttendee = calItem.Recipients.Add("Jane Doe")
            mtgAttendee.Type = olOptional
            Set mtgAttendee = calItem.Recipients.Add("CR 101")
            mtgAttendee.Type = olResource
            calItem.Save
            If (calItem.Recipients.ResolveAll) Then
                calItem.Send
            Else
                calItem.Display
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objPane = Nothing
    Set objModule = Nothing
    Set objGroup = Nothing
    Set objNavFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set calItem = Nothing
    Set mtgAttendee = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/excel-vba-create-an-appointment-in-someone-elses/4c2ec8d1-82f2-4b02-abb7-8c2de2fd7656?auth=1